# c# workflow variable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I am working on a c# project using Windows Workflow Foundation. I am coding some custom Activities and I am not using the designer. I have the following code which I am assigning to a local variable for a while activity. How do I to access the value of StepNo inside the while activity? Any help please?

```
While wfWhile = new While();

//temporary Assign activity, remove it later
Variable<int> stepNo = new Variable<int>("stepNo", 0);  

wfWhile.Variables.Add(stepNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Different ways of doing this but a `VisualBasicValue<T>` is the way it is done most of the time. The following code loops around until stepNo becomes 10, prints the value of stepNo and increment it.

```
While wfWhile = new While();
Variable<int> stepNo = new Variable<int>("stepNo", 0);
wfWhile.Variables.Add(stepNo);

wfWhile.Body = new Sequence()
{
    Activities = {
        new WriteLine
        {
            Text = new VisualBasicValue<string>("\"Step: \" & stepNo ")
        },
        new Assign<int>()
        {
                To = new OutArgument<int>(stepNo),
                Value= new VisualBasicValue<int>("stepNo + 1")
        }

        }
};
wfWhile.Condition = new VisualBasicValue<bool>("stepNo < 10");
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wfWhile);
```